# Trying to use both fade and scale effect on a jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

as the title suggests, I'm trying to use two effects on show at the same time, and have no idea how to go about doing so. The relevant code I have is:

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
open: function(){
        $('.ui-widget-overlay').hide().fadeIn(600).blur();
        $('.ui-dialog :button').blur();},
show: "fade",
modal: true,
autoOpen: true,
width: 340,
buttons: [
    {
        text: "Ok",
        tabIndex: -1,
        width: "340",
        click: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle, no worries about the style formatting I already have that in place. I just need to figure out how to both scale and fade in. Thank You!

http://jsfiddle.net/fb58386n/

Comment: Could you set up an example? At http://jsfiddle.net for instance?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is not multi threaded unless you use WebWorkers , try to create WebWorkers then run each function on one of them and tun them on the same time , make sure your CPU is at least dual core .

or take out the code from their functions and make them run gradually inside a loop from 0 to 100 .

Comment: If its not too much trouble, could you explain in a more newbie friendly way? Or post example scripts maybe. I'm not too well versed in this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a CSS `toggled` class. You set up the normal CSS for the element, and use jQuery to add the `toggled` class whenever the button to hide or open the menu is clicked. The class would look like this:

```
.toggled {
    height: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

And the script would look like this:

```
function toggleClass(){
    $("#elem_to_toggle").toggleClass("toggled");
}
```

This assumes that you are trying to make it fade out and shrink to 0 at the same time. Opacity isn't supported across all browsers, but that should get caught by `display: none;`.

Comment: I see where you're going with this, only that I don't have a trigger for my dialog, I want it to auto open as soon as the page loads. Could I still implement this idea?

Comment: You could try call an `onLoad` event or a `DOMContentLoaded` event and toggle the class then.

Comment: Try adding this event listener into you `$(document).ready`: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){$("#elem_to_toggle").toggleClass("toggled");});`